# Configure postfix for outgoing mail

Tags: email, postfix

I rent a VPS, a domain name (let's say `foo.bar`).
I want to send an email using the address `user@foo.bar`.

I have installed `postfix`, and started configured the `main.cf` file; however it doesn't work. It seems to me that the parameter `relayhost` is misconfigured. Indeed, I saw on the internet that I should put the domain name of my ISP. But what if I don't own an ISP? I could understand if the server was at my home, but it is a VPS.

You can find enclosed my configuration file. Can somebody help me to make it works?

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

# MY SERVER
myhostname = server.foo.bar
mydomain   = foo.bar

# Transport mod for outgoing mail
default_transport = smtp

# Aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128

relay_domains = $mydestination
relayhost = $mydomain

mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

myorigin = $mydomain
```

---

Here's the log file `/var/log/mail.log`:

```
Sep  9 12:12:42 foobar postfix/postfix-script[1635]: refreshing the Postfix mail system
Sep  9 12:12:42 foobar postfix/qmgr[1640]: 736F541741: from=<foobar@foobar>, size=336, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep  9 12:12:42 foobar postfix/smtp[1642]: warning: relayhost configuration problem
Sep  9 12:12:42 foobar postfix/smtp[1642]: 736F541741: to=<echo@tu-berlin.de>, relay=none, delay=374, delays=374/0.04/0.03/0, dsn=4.3.5, status=deferred (mail for foo.bar loops back to myself)
```

Comment: This is an example, I don't own it.

Comment: What makes you think it is misconfigured ? Can you post the relevant lines from /var/log/mail.log ?

Comment: Also, what is the intended usage of this postfix server ? Delivery to local users ? Forwarding to other hosts ?

Comment: I want to create email addresses like `user1@foo.bar`, `user2@foo.bar`, and so on, and use them on the internet to send/receive email.

I added the content of `/var/log/mail.log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `relayhost` parameter indeed seems to be misconfigured. More precisely, it is configured and it shouldn't be.

> The relayhost parameter specifies the default host to send mail to when no entry is matched in the optional transport(5) table. When no relayhost is given, mail is routed directly to the destination.

When on an home connexion, it makes sense to set it to the smtp server of your ISP, as your ISP may restrict access to port 25 from your internet connexion. Relaying through your provider will get rid of that problem.

On a VPS however, you can access internet directly, hopefully without any filtering. You can therefore leave it empty, and your server should attempt to deliver directly to your recipients.